# SVG Logo Stretching issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have this logo with a class called

```
.img-max-logo{
width:100%;
height:auto;
max-height:60px;
}
```

In every browser it gives me this result, works great.
[image]

In internet explorer the aspect ratio gets distorted like this:
[image]

Is there something I can do to fix this issue?

I have my doc set up like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/daugaard47/s3tXr/

Thanks for any help.

Comment: HTML & CSS in a JSfiddle please. What doctype are you using?

Comment: i would go for an heigh:100%;max-height:60px; and check if you have this viewbox attribute in SVG. your code is missing @cwd for SVG , at least the root tag :)

Comment: I added my doc type and a jsfiddle to help my issue a little more.
@GCyrillus I dont think I have that attribute in the actual svg file..?

Answer (score 0):

To use an `<img>` to insert an `<svg>` , might not be the best idea.

If you include SVG within your HTML5 code, remove `height` `width` attributes for `viewbox`, it seems to work much better . http://jsfiddle.net/s3tXr/1/

here the root tag `<svg>` where i removed `height/width` and turned it into `viewbox`.

```
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   version="1.1"

    viewbox="0 0 729 162"

   id="svg2"
   xml:space="preserve">
```